# How to bind angularJS expressions in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

Before I use html static div Id,

```
<div id="slider1">
```

and It use in JQuery like as,

```
$('#slider1').Thumbelina({
    $bwdBut:$('#slider1 .left'),    // Selector to left button.
    $fwdBut:$('#slider1 .right')    // Selector to right button.
});
```

Now I want to do it using angularJs expression like,

```
<div id="{{catagory.catagoryName}}">
```

But how to get angularjs expression value in JQuery and using this expression with JQuery code?

```
$('#slider1').Thumbelina({
    $bwdBut:$('#slider1 .left'),    // Selector to left button.
    $fwdBut:$('#slider1 .right')    // Selector to right button.
});
```

Comment: If it is defined in your controller you can access through $scope

Comment: For this don't need to control any controller.
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
   $('#slider1').Thumbelina({
    $bwdBut:$('#slider1 .left'),    // Selector to left button.
    $fwdBut:$('#slider1 .right')    // Selector to right button.
   }); 
})
</script>

Comment: jQuery isn't 'normal js'.

Comment: You can execute any jquery inside the angularjs controller, however this is not a very good practice to mess them together. Try something like:`$('#'+$scope.catagory.catagoryName).Thumbelina({
    $bwdBut:$('#slider1 .left'),    // Selector to left button.
    $fwdBut:$('#slider1 .right')    // Selector to right button.
}); `.

Comment: Its better to use angular JS slider, or you can use jquery script in controller, its not a best practice. $ replace with angular.element Tag